# Only certain part of 120 film underexposed

Tags: film

I shot a 120mm film **for the first time** on my Kiev 60 camera and 11 out of 12 photos were underexposed but only on the left side (almost totally black) like so :

[image: photo 1]
[image: photo 2]
What I did so far :

1. Tried taking pictures with the back of the camera open to see if the diaphragm opens correctly at any speed : ok
2. Made sure nothing was floating in the lense

Any ideas?

Comment: I havn't handled a Kiev 60 in a very long time, and don't have one to check, but I believe they have a horizontal curtain. It's not uncommon for cameras with this style of curtain to develop different speeds for the open and close curtains. The closing curtain moving fast enough that it competes its cycle before the open curtain has fully opened can cause this symptom. Does it get worse as you increase the shutter speed?

Comment: In Soviet Russia, Hasselbladski exposes you! Also, it’s almost most definitely a shutter problem. Time to get it serviced.

Comment: Wonder if recording the movement of the shutter at 60-120 fps could elucidate the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's almost certainly a bad shutter.  The shutter may need adjustment or replacement.  For speeds above your X-sync (the speed where the shutter is at least temporarily totally open), the shutter curtains are launched with a slight delay to have a slit cross the path of the film.  If the timing is wrong, you can end up with the two curtains being sent at inappropriate times relative to one another, and get effects like you describe.

I assume you weren't shooting with electronic flash.  If you were, then you need to reduce your shutter speed to the X-sync speed (probably 1/30 sec. on your camera).

Note, too, that 120 film isn't 120mm.  120 is just a format describer made by Kodak (35mm film is 135 under this system) and the system was adopted by other manufacturers.  120 film is actually about 65mm wide.

Enjoy, and good luck!